# How to Integrate Composite Functions

Tags: indefinite-integrals, function-and-relation-composition

Given that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are both integratable and differentiable functions, and $f(g(x))$ is also integratable, how would you find $\int f(g(x))$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125267/integrating-composite-functions-by-a-general-formula

Comment: @b00nheT There, they didn't answer my question.

Comment: @b00nheT I'd have to agree that the question you linked doesn't really answer this question.

Comment: I didn't mark the question as duplicate, but just pointed out a related question. Nonetheless, to me it's quite clear from the counterexamples listed in that question we know that even having closed forms for antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$ isn't enough for having a closed form for their composition. Thus there is no general answer for $\int f(g(x))\,dx$. But maybe I did not understand the OP's question in the first place...

Comment: @b00nheT No, you understood it perfectly, I guess there is no answer... Thanks anyway! Maybe someone else can chime in?