# Chain rule for integration: proof of non-existence

Tags: integration, chain-rule

Is there a formal proof of non-existence of chain rule formula $C$ for integration?

$$
\int f(g(x))dx = C\big[\int f(x) dx, \int g(x) dx, f(x), g(x) \big]
$$

where the question assumes the formula $C$ is finite in length (and independent on any other criteria on behavior of functions $f,g$).

It is clear some functions (e.g. $e^{-1/x^2}$) cannot be integrated within elementary functions. But $C$ might contain some new non-elementary or special functions, so existence of examples of non-elementary integrable functions as counter-example is not a valid argument.

There is a similar question with no answer I would expect:

[Integrating composite functions by a general formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125267/integrating-composite-functions-by-a-general-formula)

The non-existence of chain rule is advanced as a basic reason for "hardness" of integration, yet I am not aware of a formal proof.

EDIT: To be more rigorous: In my question $C$ should only contain fuction compostition where some new *finite* set of (some special) functions can be introduced (and presumabely must be).

Comment: Note that even if there exists such a formula, it might be entirely inpractical. Then that would still be a reason for why integration is considered to be harder

Comment: You are probably right, that my question is not precise enough because it does not speciify what $C$ can contain (differentiation? Fourrier transform?). I ment only function composition with maybe some new finite set of function. I am going to edit.